# Change Screen Resolution in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I've been plugging away at this for a few hours now, and haven't found a good answer. In Leopard, I can programmatically change the screen resolution using Quartz Display Services with **CGConfigureDisplayMode**. Unfortunately, this has been deprecated in 10.6.

This seems like a simple task: how can I change the screen resolution with non-deprecated methods in Snow Leopard?

Thanks!

Comment: There probably isn't a non-deprecated way. Large chunks of display and ColorSync related code have been marked as deprecated with no documentation and no publicly accessible replacements in sight just to make the ship date.

Comment: That would explain why I was having such a hard
time. Thanks!

Comment: Also, note that deprecated does not mean it'll break any time soon, particularly if there's no available alternative. With a few notable exceptions (e.g. the Cocoa-Java bridge) Apple has removed essentially no public APIs from OS X as of yet.

Comment: NSD, that comment is uncalled for; there are replacements for this and many other deprecated APIs.

Comment: You obviously haven't tried to use ColorSync in the last 6 years.

Comment: No, I haven’t tried to use ColorSync, but this question doesn’t relate to ColorSync in any way, and your comment was just speculation. There was a perfectly reasonable replacement for the existing API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality has been updated; take a look at `CGConfigureDisplayWithDisplayMode` in `<CoreGraphics/CGDisplayConfiguration.h>`.

Comment: This works great in Snow Leopard, but not for my particular application :( I'm looking to set the resolution permenantly, but this method "persists for the life of the program, and automatically reverts to the permanent setting when the program terminates." Thanks!

Comment: Whoops! Updated the answer to reflect your needs.